# Wrong outputs on on_message while using a random number generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, discord, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import random

class Ship(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if (message.guild.id == 464298877823221761) or (message.guild.id == 548945695034310697) or (message.guild.id == 712143774935154689):
            if message.content.find("!ship") != -1:
                line = message.content
                name = line.split(' ')[1]
                name2 = line.split(' ')[2]
                number = random.randint(0,100)
                if 0 <= number <= 10:
                    await message.channel.send(':heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n:small_red_triangle_down:`' + name +'`'+ '\n:small_red_triangle:`' + name2 + '`' + '\n**' + str(number) + '%** Awful :sob:')
                    number = random.randint(0,100)
                if 11 <= number <= 19:
                    await message.channel.send(':heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n:small_red_triangle_down:`' + name +'`'+ '\n:small_red_triangle:`' + name2 + '`' + '\n**' + str(number) + '%** Bad :cry:')
                    number = random.randint(0,100)
                if 20 <= number <= 29:
                    await message.channel.send(':heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n:small_red_triangle_down:`' + name +'`'+ '\n:small_red_triangle:`' + name2 + '`' + '\n**' + str(number) + '%** Pretty Low :frowning:')
                    number = random.randint(0,100)
                if 30 <= number <= 39:
                    await message.channel.send(':heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n:small_red_triangle_down:`' + name +'`'+ '\n:small_red_triangle:`' + name2 + '`' + '\n**' + str(number) + '%** Not Great :confused:')
                    number = random.randint(0,100)
                if 40 <= number <= 49:
                    await message.channel.send(':heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n:small_red_triangle_down:`' + name +'`'+ '\n:small_red_triangle:`' + name2 + '`' + '\n**' + str(number) + '%** Not Too Bad :confused:')
                    number = random.randint(0,100)
                if 50 <= number <= 59:
                    await message.channel.send(':heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n:small_red_triangle_down:`' + name +'`'+ '\n:small_red_triangle:`' + name2 + '`' + '\n**' + str(number) + '%** Barely :no_mouth:')
                    number = random.randint(0,100)
                if 60 <= number <= 69:
                    await message.channel.send(':heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n:small_red_triangle_down:`' + name +'`'+ '\n:small_red_triangle:`' + name2 + '`' + '\n**' + str(number) + '%** Not Bad :slight_smile:')
                    number = random.randint(0,100)
                if 70 <= number <= 79:
                    await message.channel.send(':heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n:small_red_triangle_down:`' + name +'`'+ '\n:small_red_triangle:`' + name2 + '`' + '\n**' + str(number) + '%** Pretty Good :smiley:')
                    number = random.randint(0,100)
                if 80 <= number <= 89:
                    await message.channel.send(':heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n:small_red_triangle_down:`' + name +'`'+ '\n:small_red_triangle:`' + name2 + '`' + '\n**' + str(number) + '%** Great :smile:')
                    number = random.randint(0,100)
                if 90 <= number <= 99:
                    await message.channel.send(':heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n:small_red_triangle_down:`' + name +'`'+ '\n:small_red_triangle:`' + name2 + '`' + '\n**' + str(number) + '%** Amazing :heart_eyes:')
                    number = random.randint(0,100)
                elif 100 == number:
                    await message.channel.send(':heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n:small_red_triangle_down:`' + name +'`'+ '\n:small_red_triangle:`' + name2 + '`' + '\n**' + str(number) + '%** **PERFECT** :heart_exclamation:')
                    number = random.randint(0,100)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Ship(bot))
```

I think that title sums it up, when I turn the bot on and type in `!ship` followed by 2 names the code spits out 2 messages but the second time I type in the command I get 1 output as intended

please look in the comments of this question for more info about my problem

Comment: "if (number >= 0) or (number <= 10):" Did you try these conditions in isolation? What happens if you test whether, for example `(20 >= 0) or (20 <= 10)`? What do you expect `or` to do here? Look at your screenshot; did you notice that the `number`  values accompanying each message don't really make sense for what the message is?

Comment: Also: why are you re-picking the `number` and then trying to test whether the *new* value is within a *different* range? Did you want all of these tests to operate on the same number? Are you familiar with `elif`? But separately, why re-pick `number` at all?

Comment: I made a rookie mistake by not using `elif`, I updated the question and screenshot @KarlKnechtel

Comment: Right; you still have the logical problem with how the conditions are written. In Python, you can write the condition [in a way that is simpler and less prone to error](https://realpython.com/python-operators-expressions/#chained-comparisons): `if 0 <= number <= 10:`. Except, think about it more carefully: do you really want `<=` on both sides? If the number is `10`, which bracket should it fall into?

Comment: Thank you so much @KarlKnechtel only one problem remains when I turn on the bot and the first time I type in the command I get 2 outputs, the second time I type the command I get one output as intended, I updated the question as well

Comment: *That* part probably has to do with how discord.py works and I don't have the specific knowledge to help you with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in your conditions.

See first condition for example :

```
if (number >= 0) or (number <= 10):
```

This will take ANY number. You want number >= 0 AND number <= 10.

By the way you can do it like this:

```
if 0 <= number <= 10:
```

Also you shouldn't randomize a new number in each condition.

One last thing, you seem to do it 10 by 10, so you can do something much easier like :

```
labels = {0: "awful", 1: "bad", 2 : "decent", ...}
number = random.randint(0,100)
label = labels[int(number/10)]
await message.channel.send(
  f"heartpulse:**MATCHMAKING**:heartpulse:\n
    :small_red_triangle_down:`{name}`\n
    :small_red_triangle:`{name2}`\n
    **{number}%** **{label}** :heart_exclamation:")
```

Comment: This answer not only showed me the right answer to my problem but showed me a whole new level of programming, I never really saw how simple and short code can be. I am young at only 16 and have been playing around with code for a while now, but this, just wow. THANKS for the help, it's my dream to become a computer programmer at one of the big tech companies.

Comment: Coding discord bots at 16 is great you are definitely on the good path to reach your dreams ;)